# Django admin - how to store references to models in model field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-apps

I'm making some big changes in Django Admin and need to make an application to group various models to groups and then show it in menu.
I have a function to generate list of all available admin models including permissions.
So I make 1 model to add group (id, name). Via Inlines I want to add specific models to groups.
What is the best way to store models references? Should I store it as string and during my menu is generated I should parse the name, find specific model and generate its url in admin?

Thanks for clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) would help you.